# jQuery button click only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to hide and show elements on a button click. I have the following code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#link-form').hide()
  $('#link-submit').hide()

  $('#main-header-submit').on("click", function() {
    $('#link-form').show();
    $('#main-yield').fadeTo("fast", 0.2)
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $('#link-form').hide()
      $('#main-yield').fadeTo("fast", 1)
    })
  })
})
```

This successfully shows and hides the divs when I click the `'main-header-submit'` button, but when I click the button (effectively for a third time) to make the elements show again nothing happens. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Because your code isn't right. You trying to show and hide `#link-form` in your click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite your code like this, it should work:

```
$(function(){
  $('#main-header-submit').on("click", function() {
    $('#link-form').toggle("fast");
  })
})
```

The `toggle` function hides the elements if they are shown and shows them if they are hidden. Check here http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

use `toggle()` and `fadeToggle`

```
$('#main-header-submit').on("click", function() {
  $('#link-form').toggle();
  $('#main-yield').fadeToggle("fast")
})
```

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal Read question exactly before posting answer

Comment: use `.one` where you want one time click

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP **DOES NOT** want a one time click.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're attaching another `click` handler on each successive click. The first shows the `link-form`, while the second hides it. This is why you never see any change.

From what I can see of your code, to achieve what you require you simply need to use `toggle()` and `fadeTo()` with a ternary instead. Try this:

```
$('#main-header-submit').on("click", function() {
    $('#link-form').toggle();
    $('#main-yield').fadeTo("fast", $('#main-yield').css('opacity') == '1' ? 0.2 : 1);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pdy9u5Lo/)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, using `$("selector").on('click', function() { ... });` will run the `...` on the click event for that element.

Inside the `...` function definition, you're overwriting the `.on('click')` by another function.

So in other words, the first time you click, you're telling the code to show your element, then rebind the click to hide. So every subsequent click will hide the already hidden element.

What you need to do is to something like this:

```
$('#main-header-submit').on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":visible")){
    $('#link-form').hide()
    $('#main-yield').fadeTo("fast", 1)
  }
  else{
    $('#link-form').show();
    $('#main-yield').fadeTo("fast", 0.2)
  }
});
```

Comment: Why you post answer while you don't readed question? Click event work for one and question is about solving it but your answer suggest `.one()`!

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks for the correction `.one()` was a typo.